# (PHP-Yii-UserGroups) Cron Job executing without stop

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

So, I have a cron job with the following code:

```
class UGCJReminder extends UGCronJob {
/**
 * return the cron description
 */
protected function getDescription()
{
    return Yii::t('userGroupsModule.cron', 'manda email para os usuarios cadastrados para cadastrar suas atividades');
}

/**
 * return the cron table model name
 */
protected function getCronTable()
{
    return 'UserGroupsCron';
}

/**
 * return the cron name
 */
protected function getName()
{
    return 'reminder';
}

/**
 * returns the number of days that have to pass before performing this cron job
 */
protected function getLapse()
{
    return 1;
}

/**
 * return the model
 */
protected function getModel()
{
    return new UserGroupsUser;
}

/**
 * return the action method
 */
protected function getAction()
{
        Yii::import('ext.yii-mail.YiiMailMessage');
        $message = new YiiMailMessage;
        $message->setBody('Message', 'text/html');
        $message->subject = 'Lembrete';
        $message->addTo('my-email');
        $message->from = Yii::app()->params['adminEmail'];
        return Yii::app()->mail->send($message);
}

/**
 * return the action criteria
 */
protected function getCriteria()
{
            return new CDbCriteria;
}

/**
 * return the interested database fields
 */
protected function getColumns()
 {
        return array('email' => UserGroupsUser::ACTIVE);
        #return NULL;
 }
}
```

I do all the other changes on documentation that UserGroups (Yii module) asks, and the cron list says my cron is installed and running. However, it runs multiple times a day, where it should only run once per day. So what I'm doing wrong?

I would also accept another solution for this problem (sending a email on a determined time per day). Please consider that I'm using Yii and as such would like a way of doing this inside the framework (with extensions for example)

PS: If you know good documentation sources (since Usergroups, Cron-tab and Yii itself isn't that strong on documenting how all this works) about all this I would still be interested on that

Answer (score 0):

I never used this extenstion before.
But I am look at the source code and pay attention at this fragment:

https://github.com/nickcv/userGroups/blob/master/components/UGCron.php#L206

```
if ($cItem->last_occurrence <= date('Y-m-d', time() - (3600 * 24 * $cItem->lapse)).' 00:00:00') {
    ...
    $cItem->last_occurrence = date('Y-m-d').' 00:00:00';                    
    $cItem->save();
}
```

And I want to ask you next questions:

1. Does `if` operator works properly in your case?
2. Does `$cItem->last_occurrence` become updated after cron run?
3. What version of PHP do you use?

Comment: Since the cron job loads immediately after I click on cron jobs tab (on usergroups admin page) I can't enter in this part of the code to check. I suspect that it's somewhat because of that but  I ended using the server crontab to do what I needed. Thanks for the answer :)